# SQL Server import export wizard converts views to tables

Tags: sql-server, import, export

I'm trying to create a development copy of our database on

```
Microsoft SQL Server Web (64-bit) 11.0.5388.0
```

to a

```
Microsoft SQL Server Developer (64-bit) 14.0.3048.4
```

running in linux docker.

I tried the SQL Server import export wizard, and, while it transferred the tables fine, the views on the source became tables on the destination.

This is of cause not acceptable, and as some of the views are quite complicated and only intended to run once in a while, not optimized. So when the import of the views had taken for times the time of the table import, I terminated it.

I could see no option to convert views to tables, and I also don't see the point in doing it.

So what am I doing wrong?

Any suggestions?

If I do a backup, and want to do a restore, it appears the file have to be on the same machine as the database; it is not possible to do a restore from a file on a webserver; as the source machine is also a webserver.

I don't have room on the destination server for both database and backup file; but I have enough room on my workstation; if I run docker on both destination and workstation, can I mount a volume from workstation on destination?

Comment: You don't have the have the backup file on the same host as the data engine, no. You *can* restore from a file share. If you add the share (temporarily if needed) onyour Linux host, and allow the `mssql` user or group to read from it, it'll be able to restore from the remote location. Note, however, it will likely be slow due to the file being pulled over the network.

Comment: Could you script out the views from the web instance and run it on the development instance?  In SQL Server Management Studio you can use the Object Explorer Details (F7 keyboard shortcut) to multi-select the views and script the create statements.

Comment: Possibly. At the moment I have created a backup, and it is mount.cifs'ed on the destination server. Now I "just" need to make the backup visible inside the container.

Comment: The restore completed, including views, functions and procedures. Under an hour for 34GB, 100Mbps network to a dual core Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N455   @ 1.66GHz. Just for development ;-)